# Best way to concatenate short strings in Python

Tags: python, string, concatenation

For example, if I'm just printing out an error, is it better to do

`print "Error encountered: " + error.args[0]`

or

`print ''.join("Error encountered: ", error.args[0])`

or perhaps

`print "Error encountered: {0}".format(error.args[0])`

Which one would be the fastest, and which would be the most "Pythonic" way to do it?

Comment: For "fastest", you need to just try it. I suspect it'll be quite close and may even depend on the particular implementation

Answer (score 4):

This is generally the best way

```
print "Error encountered: {0}".format(error.args[0])
```

When you need to [internationalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalisation#Coding_practice) you application, you can often just go

```
print _("Error encountered: {0}").format(error.args[0])
```

And let [gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) to the rest of the work

If there are multiple argumnent's it's best to use the mapping version

```
print _("Error encountered: {err}").format(err=error.args[0])
```

So it'll still work if a translation needs to move the order of the arguments around

Answer (score 2):

No need to concatenate strings. Just print them.

```
print "Error encountered:", error.args[0]
```

Comment: @ron975: Note that the `print` statement prints a space between consecutive arguments. This is not always what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate two strings using several different techniques:

```
str1 = 'Hello'
str2 = 'there!'

print (str1, str2)
```

The use of the comma between variables in a print statement automatically inserts a space between the items that are output. If you had used a plus sign, i.e., print (str1 + str2), the above output would look like 'HelloWorld'.

Hope this helps.

Caitlin

Comment: The OP is using Python2 - we can tell since `print` is being used as a statement. This is the Python3 version of @falsetru's answer

Comment: Ah, yes. I noticed that. Wouldn't the syntax I used apply to Python 2 as well though?

Comment: Just try it. You'll see that it prints the 2-tuple instead of just the two strings.

Comment: You can use `from __future__ import print_function` though